# Sum two columns together in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

In Tableau, I am trying to figure out how to sum up the percentages of two columns. I calculated the **percentages** using the percentages of command and used the table option, from the analysis menu. This generated the table shown below. I would like a column that sums the 4 and 5 columns together to show a total percentage of 59.76 which is 26.83+32.93 from columns 4 and 5. How would I create this calculated field?

[image]

How I generated the percentages:

[image]

Comment: Hi, you could try dragging your calculated fields onto the 'measures' section so that they become fixed calculation, then making a third calculated field that sums them both together, does this give you the desired result?

Comment: Right click on your measure, choose Edit Table Calc and experiment to see your choices. Read about addressing and partitioning in the table calculation section of the on-line help.